# XML, probably simple errors that i can't find (exam XML)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

So we've had an exam (which i failed) about XML after a couple of hours staring at an xPath error I've come here for help.

```
<!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
     syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
-->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StylesheetWorkoutWimVanoverwalle.css" />
            <title>Workouts by Wim Van Overwalle and friends</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Workouts by Wim Van Overwalle and Friends</h1>
            <p>Total Number of workouts By Wim Van Overwalle</p>
            <div>
            <xsl:value-of select ="sum(workout)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="workouts/workout/@type='running'">
                <xsl:sort select="workout/starttime"
                          order = "ascending"
                          data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:value-of select = "naam"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="distance/@km"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="starttime/@date"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="location/@country"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="distance/@km"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="duration"/>                                      
            </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
            <xsl:for-each select="workouts/workout[@type='cycling']">
                <xsl:value-of select = "naam"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="distance/@km"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="starttime/@date"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="location/@country"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="distance/@km"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="duration"/>                                      
            </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:for-each select="workouts/workout[@type='running']">
                  <xsl:value-of select = "naam"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="distance/@km"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="starttime/@date"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="location/@country"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="distance/@km"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="duration"/> 
             </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

^XSL file

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name = "workouts">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref= "workout"
                        minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name= "workout">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "person"/>
            <xs:element name = "starttime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name = "distance" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name= "duration" type="xs:time"/>
            <xs:element name="avgpace" type="xs:time"/>
            <xs:element name = "location">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="country">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base= "xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z]"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name= "type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value='running'/>
                    <xs:enumeration value='cycling'/>
                    <xs:enumeration value='walking'/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

^xsd file

```
workouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="WorkoutsWimVanoverWalle.xsd">
    <workout type="running">
        <person>Wim Van Overwalle</person>
        <starttime>2016-05-11T07:36:00</starttime>
        <distance unit="km">6.09</distance>
        <duration>00:36:50</duration>
        <avgpace>00:05:52</avgpace>
        <location country="BE">Kortrijk</location>
    </workout>
```

^ a part of my xml file

getting an a error that says: "error during xslt-transformation: a NodeSet was expected as result of a xPath-Expression" Help please :/

Comment: I'm getting an errpr while the XSTL-transformation is going on a NodeSet was expected as result of a xPath-expression

Comment: Don't apologize for a question that's too long and too broad and then just leave it too long and too broad.  **Fix it.**

Comment: Well tbh i'd just want to get a fix for the xPath issue because i can't find it. Like i've been trying stuff for 3 hours can't find anything :/

Comment: Please [edit] your post and copy-paste actual files that produce the error. Please reduce your files to the **smallest** possible, yet still **complete** example that reproduces the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

When I run `xsltproc`, I get the following error message:

```
runtime error: file foo.xsl line 17 element for-each
The 'select' expression does not evaluate to a node set.
```

The line in question is:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="workouts/workout/@type='running'">
```

Perhaps you meant to say this instead:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="workouts/workout[@type='running']">
```

Comment: yh that was a mistake, thanks but still getting the xPath error

Comment: After fixing that error, your code runs perfectly for me. Please edit your post to include actual sample code (shorten what you have and make it complete and runnable), along with instructions on how to recreate the problem.